# What's the relationship between document.write() and AJAX?

Tags: ajax, document.write

I am not familiar with AJAX.

Does `document.write()` broadly used in AJAX technique?

Is there any relationship between them?

Comment: AJAX and `document.write()` are unrelated, unless you want to [snap two blocks together](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/08/04/9856634.aspx) to solve a particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.write()` and AJAX are really antithetical.  AJAX is typically used to update some DOM element(s) based on he results of an synchronous call, whereas `document.write()` if used after the page have been loaded, will actually clear the content of the entire document, replacing it with whatever value is passed to the function.